# Jquery if not mouseover statement

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement

I am trying to work with some jQuery and HTML.

I have two `div` element containers containing various content. The two elements are adjacent to one another. The divs do not contain one another. I have the code written so that when I mouseover one div (`div#1`), the other div (`div#2`) slides down (`.slideDown`).

Also, when you mouseout `div#2`, `div#2` slides up (`.slideUp`).

The problem is that if `div#2` is already slid down, and if you mouseover `div#1` again, `div#2` will slide up and back down again. This is pretty annoying and unprofessional. I need it to slide up only if my mouse is not over `div#1`.

This is my goal: I need to find a jQuery statement that says,
"Only if the mouse is "out" of `div#2` and **not "over"** `div#1`, slide `div#2` up."

Is this possible?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.stop()` to stop the animation before re-animating the element. This will prevent the queue from filling up with repetitive animations:

```
$('#stop').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({width: '250px'});
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({width: '150px'});
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/2TkNc/2/**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you should do like this:

```
$('.div1').die('mouseover').live('mouseover',function(){
                                     $('.div2').slideDown();
                                     });
$('.div2').die('mouseover hover').live('mouseout',function(){
                                     $('.div2').slideUp();
                                     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2TkNc/5/